# Is a set A a subset of B if all of the elements of A are within sets within B?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How "deep" does the subset operator go?

If I have a set *A* = {1, 1, 2} and a set *B* = {1, {2}, {1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, is *A* a subset of *B*?

Thanks

Comment: No, $A$ is a subset of $B$ if all the elements of $A$ are ***elements*** of $B$. In your example, the elements of $A$ are $1$ and $2$. Is $2$ an element of $B$?

Comment: No, $A$ is not a subset of $B$ because $2\in A, 2\notin B$.  Also note that $A=\{1,2\}, B= \{1,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

Comment: No. Sets and elements are entirely different and the subset operator goes 0 levels.  Not deep at all.  A set has elements. If those elements are sets then what is inside those sets will *NEVER* have anything to do with the set at all, and a subset is only as set whose elements are all elements of the original set.  NOT elements within elements, and NOT sets made out of elements.  ONLY elements that are in the original set and ONLY at the very top level.

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Sometimes the non negative integers at defined by $0=\emptyset$ and by $x^+:=\{x\}$. In this case $2=\{1\}$, where $x^+$ denotes the _successor_ of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is a subset of $B$ if and only if $a\in B$ for all $a\in A$, by definition. This does not involve any depth at all: $2\notin B$ and $2\in A$, therefore $A\nsubseteq B$.